# Giving structure to a flat data array

Tags: arrays, json, python-2.7, multidimensional-array

I have some tricky data to deal with. Basically I want to give structure to a flattened list.

In plain English, it should make:

1. `"level":1` tags be key of the array
2. `"level":2` or higher tags should be nested within an array
3. If no `"level":1`,  add it to a generic `NoLevel1` list
4. It should group `tags` together only `if` they have the same `"level":1` value

My data looks like this:

```
[{
  "title": "Set 1",
  "tag": [{
    "name": "Animals",
    "level": 1
  },
  { "name": "Cat",
    "level": 2
  },
  { "name": "Dog",
    "level": 3
  }
]
},
{
  "title": "Set 2",
  "tag": [{
    "name": "Fruits",
    "level": 1
  },
  { "name": "Apple",
    "level": 2
  }]
},
{
  "title": "Set 3",
  "tag": [{
    "name": "Fruits",
    "level": 1
  },
  { "name": "Orange",
    "level": 3
  }]
},
{
  "title": "Set 4",
  "tag": [{
    "name": "Cars",
    "level": 2
  }]
},
{
  "title": "Set 5",
  "tag": [{
    "name": "Random!",
    "level": 3
  }]
}]
```

My desired output is this:

```
[{
  "name": "Animals",
  "level":1,
  "tag_child": [{
    "name": "Cat",
    "level": 2
  },
  { "name": "Dog",
    "level": 3
  }]
},
  {
  "name": "Fruits",
  "level":1,
  "tag_child": [{
    "name": "Apple",
    "level": 2
  },
  { "name": "Orange",
    "level": 3
  }]
},
  {
  "name": "NoLevel1",
  "level":1,
  "tag_child": [{
    "name": "Cars",
    "level": 2
  },
  { "name": "Random!",
    "level": 3
  }]
}]
```

I have loaded the data, but have not gotten further in terms of giving the data its structure.

```
import json

with open("Test.json") as json_file:
    l = json_data = json.load(json_file)
for i in thedata:
    if i['tag']['level'] > 1:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test this, but something like this should work. Make your own changes if this is not what you are looking for. But definitely this should get you started.

```
import json
with open("Test.json") as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)
    generic = []
    result = []
for i in json_data:
    if any(d['level'] == 1 for d in i['tag']):
        tag_data = {}
        tag_child = []
        for tag in i['tag']:
            if tag['level'] == 1:
                tag_data['name'] = tag['name']
                tag_data['level'] = 1
            else:
                tag_child.append(tag)
        filtered = {tuple((k, d[k]) for k in sorted(d) if k in ['name']): d for d in tag_child}
        tag_data['tag_child'] = list(filtered.values())
        if any(d['name'] == tag_data['name']  for d in result):
            for t in result:
                if t['name'] == tag_data['name']:
                    t['tag_child'] = t['tag_child'] + tag_child
            filtered = {tuple((k, d[k]) for k in sorted(d) if k in ['name']): d for d in t['tag_child']}
            t['tag_child'] = list(filtered.values())
        else:
            result.append(tag_data)
    else:
        for tag in i['tag']:
            generic.append(tag)
tag_data = {}
tag_data['name'] = 'NoLevel1'
tag_data['level'] = 1
tag_data['tag_child'] = generic
result.append(tag_data)
print(json.dumps(result))
```

Comment: That is almost there- however it is treating each `"level":1` as a new item, whereas it should be combining them when they are the same. This is what your code resulted: http://dpaste.com/3D1NHZC

Comment: I just gave you something to get started. I made some changes now. Can you check.

Comment: Awesome, almost there. The last change is that results get repeated inside of `tag_child`. How would I modify to say only unique "name" values?

Comment: can you gimme the current result in dpaste

Comment: what was the input you gave?

Comment: This was not in the question. Your new input has Dog and Dogs which are different. But I think you meant Dog. I have made that change in code. If there are more changes please do it by yourself. This answer is already beyond what you asked :)

Comment: Thank you. You're correct- `Dog` twice.  Still, your sample does not seem to be removing duplicate values. Will the matching care if there are more values than just `level` and `name`? In my data, there are more fields (eg http://dpaste.com/3YRH3F9). But I only wanted the fields `name` and `level` returned anyway. I had tried understating it in your code also & do appreciate your help :)